# Existing posts hidden after WP import

Tags: import, export

I migrated a collection of posts (with attachments box checked) from one wp installation to another using the native Importer/Exporter.

On import, all the existing posts/pages on the destination site have become invisible in the backend. They are still visible on the frontend, and in the database.

Too many changes have been made in the past 24 hrs for me to return to my database backup if it can be helped.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: There's no sensible reason I can think of they'd be invisible in the back end. Do you have any plugins that filter visible posts in the backend, that might be missing metadata for the imported posts? Are you looking as an admin user?

Comment: Yes you were correct, was Polylang. One of the language names clashed and it responded by only displaying that language, which were all new posts. Thanks.